# How to make my program(exe) to stop(and not exit) once an event(generation of a text file) has occured?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exe, goto

I am creating an executable in visual studio.

My code goes like this:

```
if(condition)
    goto Step 1
else
    goto Step 2


Step 1:
code


Step 2:
code
```

I want to make this in a way that if Step 1 has run then Step 2 must be skipped.

Should it be done using functions?

Comment: Please don't use goto unless you have a very good reason.  Functions, in this case, are almost certainly better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your class It can be placed in two functions and called from the if - else logic or you can place the code in between the if and else. If the code is large then it would be better to create two functions.

```
If (condition)
   call function step1
else
   call function step2

or 

if (condition)
  code...
else
  code...
```

[C# Example of defining a method and calling it:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

```
    public void Caller()
{
    int numA = 4;
    // Call with an int variable. 
    int productA = Square(numA);

    int numB = 32;
    // Call with another int variable. 
    int productB = Square(numB);

    // Call with an integer literal. 
    int productC = Square(12);

    // Call with an expression that evaulates to int.
    productC = Square(productA * 3);
}

int Square(int i)
{
    // Store input argument in a local variable. 
    int input = i;
    return input * input;
}
```

Comment: I did that with your second suggestion but was unable to use functions :(    It is more complex to use functions in C# than in C.

Comment: @ABX Post your actual code if you're having issues. Using functions in C# isn't really any more complex than in C. Both are quite simple (and fundamental aspects of the languages).

Comment: Updated answer with link and example of how to create and call a function in C#